# Hibernate.xml file issue with <session-factory> tag

Tags: java, hibernate

I have given the code below of my hibernate.cfg.xml file. While I was writing the code following a tutorial, I have encountered an error which states

> The content of element type "session-factory" must match
> "(property*,mapping*,(class-cache|collection-cache)*,event*,listener*)".

[image: code with error in IntellIj]

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!--    url-->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/</property>
        <!--    username-->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>>
        <!--    password-->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Feelslikedope</property>
        <!--    mysql driver-->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am not able to find any proper solution for this type of error. One more thing is that when i am trying to change the SYSTEM to PUBLIC there is an error occurs which states there should be some white space after systemID.

Comment: `<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>>` remove the last `>` in that line

Comment: I noticed that rn. TQ. Solved.